# Parallel.Foreach with MSMQ

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, msmq

I am trying to run in a Parallel foreach loop on all messages I have in my queue, but I am getting this error:

Error: Property Body was not retrieved when receiving the message. Ensure that the PropertyFilter is set correctly.

When I do the same loop with a foreach (without the parallel), it all works good.

Any idea what should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue(v=vs.100).aspx) only the `GetAllMessages` method is thread safe.
 
The thread safe way for reading the queue asynchronously seems to be shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5276822/66849).

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503954/how-to-process-msmq-messages-in-parallel

Comment: @Ido Lazar: Are you just viewing the messages or removing them from the queue?

Answer (score 5):

Look like you are using not thread safe method, as per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.aspx)

> Only the GetAllMessages method is thread safe

Answer (score 2):

`Peek()` and `Receive()` (and variations thereof) are *not* thread safe. You'll need to come up with a blocking mechanism in order to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel processing will not work for taking messages off the queue as it is sequential and (if configured) transactional.

If you remove A and B, and processing for A fails, it would be returned to the queue - but B has been removed as well?

`GetAllMessages()` will return all of them, but will not remove them. You need to use 
`Receive()` for each message individually to remove it completely from the queue.